# Select column based on sum of another column

Tags: sql, t-sql

Let's say I have

```
SalesManagerId, SaleAmount, ProductId
```

I want to sum up the `SaleAmount` for each (`SalesManagerId`, `ProductId`) and grab the `ProductId` with the maximum `sum(SaleAmount)`.

Is this possible in one query?

Example:

```
1, 100, 1
1, 200, 1
1, 600, 1
1, 400, 2
2, 100, 3
3, 100, 4
3, 100, 4
2, 500, 6
3, 100, 5
```

result:

```
1, 900, 1
2, 500, 6
3, 200, 4
```

Comment: Ok, after back-and-forth in my post I finally realize what you are asking for. You said you want to "sum up the SaleAmount for each (SalesManagerId, ProductId) and grab the ProductId with the maximum sum(SaleAmount)" -- now please add "for each SalesManagerId" to the beginning of that clause. It was not clear that you want exactly one row *per manager*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have analytic functions available, you can use a `RANK()`

Something like:

```
SELECT SalesManagerId, ProductId, Total
FROM (
  SELECT SalesManagerId,
         ProductId, 
         SUM(SaleAmount) as Total,
         RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY SalesManagerId 
                     ORDER BY SUM(SaleAmount) DESC) as R
  FROM <Table name>
  GROUP BY SalesManagerId, ProductId) as InnerQuery
WHERE InnerQuery.R = 1
```

Comment: +1 Better than what I cooked up. One note: You're missing the FROM portion of your inner SELECT.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I have added the FROM placeholder.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming at least SQL 2005 so you can use a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx):

```
;with cteTotalSales as (
    select SalesManagerId, ProductId, SUM(SaleAmount) as TotalSales
        from YourSalesTable
        group by SalesManagerId, ProductId
),
cteMaxSales as (
    select SalesManagerId, MAX(TotalSales) as MaxSale
        from cteTotalSales
        group by SalesManagerId
)
select ts.SalesManagerId, ms.MaxSale, ts.ProductId
    from cteMaxSales ms
        inner join cteTotalSales ts
            on ms.SalesManagerId = ts.SalesManagerId
                and ms.MaxSale = ts.TotalSales
    order by ts.SalesManagerId
```

Comment: What are the advantages of this over the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109622/select-column-based-on-sum-of-another-column/4109768#4109768

Comment: Axn's solution is superior to what I've cooked up here as it will accomplish the task in a single pass on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP BY and ORDER:

```
SELECT SalesManagerId, SUM(SaleAmount) AS SaleSum, ProductId FROM [table-name] GROUP BY SalesManagerId, ProductId ORDER BY SaleSum DESC
```

Comment: This doesn't work; it returns multiple rows for the same `SalesManagerId`. I want only the one with the max `SaleSum`.

Comment: Sorry, I justed made an edit to add "LIMIT 1" to the end of the query to just return the top row.

Comment: `LIMIT 1` isn't valid in T-SQL. (I should have specified T-SQL in advance.)

Comment: Sorry, just realized I mis-read your post. You want the aggregates per product correct? So SalesmanagerId doesn't matter. Please see my edit. That should return the results you specified -- the first return value will be the max.

Comment: @Monogonator: In TSQL it's `SELECT TOP 1 ...`

Comment: @Ben Lee: No, please see the example. `SalesManagerId` is not irrelevant. Here's another way to think of it: for each `SalesManagerId`, return the `ProductId` with maximum total `SaleAmount`.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft: That returns exactly one row and it's clear there should be more than one row in the result set here.

Answer (score -2):

Very good question!

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(SUM(SaleAmount)), ProductId GROUP BY SalesManagerId, ProductId;
```

Or alternatively

```
SELECT SUM(SaleAmount) as Sum, ProductId GROUP BY SalesManagerId, ProductId ORDER BY Sum DESC;
```

You can't just drop the sum column and get ONLY the product id